# gdb: do not break when watchpoint on local variable goes out of scope

Tags: multithreading, gdb, command, watch

I have an application that basically creates a thread many times.  I would like to watch changes to a local variable on these threads.  I can install a watchpoint dynamically by setting a breakpoint after the variable was initialized, which then automatically installs a watch point whenever such a thread is run:

```
break somefile.c:123
commands
watch myvar
continue
end
```

This seems to work great, except that every time one of these threads terminates, gdb breaks with the following message:

`Watchpoint 3 deleted because the program has left the block in which its expression is valid.`

Which makes sense, because the local variable is going out of scope.  But is there any way to make gdb *not* break when this happens, so that the application keeps running without me having to hit continue countless of times?

Comment: If you do `maint info breakpoints`, you'll see a hidden breakpoint, something like `-26`, whose purpose is to remove the watchpoint when your current function finishes. I think the sane thing for gdb to do is to warn you about the watchpoint going out of scope and continue the program, not remain stopped. If there isn't already a setting to do this, someone can put in a feature request to the developers.